# Extract value from PDF file to variable

Tags: c#, parsing, pdf, itext, pdf-parsing

I am trying to get "Invoice number", in this case `INV-3337` from PDF file and would like to store it as variable for future use in the code.

Currently I am working on example and using this PDF for test purposes:
https://slicedinvoices.com/pdf/wordpress-pdf-invoice-plugin-sample.pdf

With my current code I am able to parse whole content to `.txt` format. Can somebody guide me how to get only needed value and store it into variable? Can it be done directly with `itextsharp`? Or do I need to parse first all to .txt file, then parse .txt file, store value as variable, delete .txt file and proceed forward?

Note! There will be a lot of PDF files to parse in real setup.

Here is my current code:

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;


namespace PDF_parser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string filePath = @"C:\temp\parser\Invoice_Template.pdf";
            string outPath = @"C:\temp\parser\Invoice_Template.txt";
            int pagesToScan = 2;

            string strText = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filePath);

                for (int page = 1; page <= pagesToScan; page++) //(int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++) <- for scanning all the pages in A PDF
                {
                    ITextExtractionStrategy its = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
                    strText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, its);

                    strText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strText)));
                    //creating the string array and storing the PDF line by line
                    string[] lines = strText.Split('\n');
                    foreach (string line in lines)
                    {
                        //Creating and appending to a text file
                        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(outPath, true))
                        {
                            file.WriteLine(line);
                        }
                    }
                }

                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Did I understand it right?

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;


namespace PDF_parser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string filePath = @"C:\temp\parser\Invoice_Template.pdf";
            string outPath = @"C:\temp\parser\Invoice_Template.txt";
            int pagesToScan = 2;

            string strText = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filePath);

                for (int page = 1; page <= pagesToScan; page++) //(int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++) <- for scanning all the pages in A PDF
                {
                    ITextExtractionStrategy its = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
                    strText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, its);

                    strText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strText)));
                    //creating the string array and storing the PDF line by line
                    string[] lines = strText.Split('\n');
                    foreach (string line in lines)
                    {
                        //Creating and appending to a text file
                        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(outPath, true))
                        {
                            // file.WriteLine(line);

                           int indexOccurrance = line.LastIndexOf("Invoice Number");
                           if(indexOccurrance > 0)
                           {
                           var invoiceNumber = line.Substring(indexOccurrance, (line.Length - indexOccurrance) );
                           }
                        }
                    }
                }

                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can find occurrence of `Invoice Number` in `line` as `int indexOccurrance = line.LastIndexOf("Invoice Number")`. Then use `substring` to get actual value .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to search for `"Invoice Number"` in each line text using `LastIndexOf`. 
If found then use `Substring` to get rest of that line (which will be `Invoice Number`)

Something like:

```
int indexOccurrance = line.LastIndexOf("Invoice Number");
if(indexOccurrance > 0)
{
  var invoiceNumber = line.Substring(indexOccurrance, (line.Length - indexOccurrance) );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Should it be done during current process or after parsing to .txt format?

Comment: @hatman Depends what you need. If you are looking only for `Invoice Number` then you can search while parsing and break out once found. If you are looking for some more info you can continue. Another thing that may affect your logic is that number of occurrence of that word. If you expect it appear multiple times then you need to look for a preceding/following anchor text.

Comment: Ok, instead of writing to txt fill I will split it to array and try to search from there. Code added by me in EDIT section does not seem to work for some reason. So maybe array search approach will do the trick

Comment: @hatman One suggestion for writing to output file. You are opening file and writing to it for each line. You can take using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(outPath, true))` about `foreach` block so that file is not open multiple times.